# How to fix Scala compilation errors? Unable to compile in idea 13.1.5

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt-idea

I'm trying to create a very simple scala application in `idea 13.1.5.`

```
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Scala Version is 2.11.2-1
```

During the **compilation**, it always complains the following **errors:**

```
Error:scalac: Error: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:53)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:102)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:105)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:257)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:257)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1376)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1229)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0$$anon$2.<init>(CompilerInterface.scala:116)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:116)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:102)
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:28)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:26)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:64)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

Comment: The problem is solved after removing the direcotry **.IdeaIC13** in the _$HOME_ directory.

Comment: Why did removal of that directory matter?

Answer (score 0):

don't know why, but delete .IdeaIC13 in the $HOME directory solves the problem

Comment: Maybe this could help to explain https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205997119-Anyone-got-scala-working-under-Intellij-14?page=1#community_comment_205776805.

Comment: java.lang.Object not found is related to a broken java runtime dependency.  When you delete .IdeaIC13 then the ide create it again right? Maybe a dirty cached configuration...