# Scala project won't compile with Bouncy Castle as dependency

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, bouncycastle

I'm trying to use Bouncy Castle in my Scala project but for some reason it won't compile. I keep getting this error:

```
Error:scalac: Error: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:53)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
...
```

I'm using IntelliJ Idea (14.0.4) with the Scala plugin (1.4). Here are my project settings:

- Java JDK 1.8.0_45
- Scala 2.11.6
- Bouncy Castle 1.52 from [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar)

How can I start debugging this issue?

Comment: Is it just with Bouncy Castle? What about other Java libraries? Is [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9103) your bug? Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290735/how-to-fix-scala-compilation-errors-unable-to-compile-in-idea-13-1-5)?

Comment: It seems that only Bouncy Castle causes this problem. The project depends on three other JARs which work just fine. The first bug is related to JDK 1.9. I don't think it's relevant. The second does resemble what I'm seeing. However, I doubt that deleting IntelliJ's directory will help.

Comment: It could just be that it's failing first on Bouncy castle. Or maybe `Error:scalac: Error: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.`  is just a generic Scala error.

Comment: I don't think so. If I remove BC it works just fine (with the other libs). Of course, it will fail at runtime because it can't find the BC provider but it does compile successfully. Is there a way to get make the compiler output more verbose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find the cause of the problem. However, I was able to work around it by adding Bouncy Castle as a Maven dependency in the Project Structure window. This fixed the issue and allowed me to use BC from Scala.